# ajax not respond in controller

Tags: php

i have followed following tutorial 
http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    // Getting all post data

       if($request->ajax()){
                //return redirect()->intended('register');

                print_r($request->All());
            }


    }
```

in the above code print not printing data .when i check console

```
POST XHR http://localhost/poet/public/account/login [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 194ms]
```

the request is ok.if i add return redirect url inside ajax  then it throw error in console

```
 POST XHR http://localhost/poet/public/account/login [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 100ms]
```

please tell me where i am doing wrong

**Update**

if i add `print_r($request->all())` then it will display in console of browser.Even if i add

```
return Redirect::to('register');
```

then whole html code will be display in console of the browser

Comment: Can you show us ur complete codes as well as the html

Comment: @Grald.same code which is mentioned in link.

Comment: What specific version did u used?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.1

Comment: The following tutorial that u've followed is for laravel 5.0

Comment: yes.but i think its not an problem

Comment: Maybe the problem is your submit token but i can't guarantee because i had encountered also like this try to check specific error in ur console

Comment: can you tell me how to send data to another page.i mean if i send user id using ajax then i need retrieve all data based on id and send that to new page

Comment: also now in my console no errors .in console i can see all data of ajax

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting a `TokenMismatchException`when you are posting using ajax. This means you are not sending the correct value of `_token`. Try this

```
//replace this
//<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
//with this
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And your `.ajaxSetup` should look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
   //instead of this
   //headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
   //use this to get the correct token value
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
});
</script>
```